# Как работают модели в Yii?

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Прошу объяснить кое-что по архитектуре Yii2 и принципу разработки приложения на нем.

Вроде бы понял суть и принципы MVC. Когда дело дошло до Yii фреймворка, охватил ступор. Вопрос касательно моделей. К примеру, я хочу реализовать вывод категорий и новостей из базы данных. В моем понимании, для этого нужна отдельно модель категорий, в ней делаем метод, который выбирает категории и возвращает их в массиве. Затем этот метод дергаем уже в контроллере и передаем в вид, где проходим циклом и все выводим. Так же и с новостями.

Теперь касательно самого фреймоврка. Куча форумов, обучающих сайтов и в том числе документация, показывают, что нужно создать модель, унаследовать ее от класса AciveRecord, в модели написать статический метод и передать имя таблицы и все, а в контроллере идет получение данных  в массив и передается виду. Возможно я не въехал в основные принципы фреймворка, но если не тяжело, то в двух словах прошу объяснить, как мне реализовать такую простейшую задачу правильно, что-бы я мог понять принцип.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Мне кажется, [самый доходчивый урок](http://srs.myrusakov.ru/yii) для новичков, правда, он не стоит тех денег.

А потом переходите [сюда](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog) это грамотный специалист.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.